# Как использовать typescript в веб программировании

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

Я использую `express` в качестве сервера. У меня простой проект:

```
.
├── src
│   └── index.html
│   └── index.ts
│   └── three.js
├── main.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Где `main.js`:

```
import * as express from 'express'

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('src'))

app.listen(80)
```

И где `index.html` пустой HTML файл, в теге `<head>` которого только тег `<title>`, а тег `<body>` абсолютно пустой, после которого я разместил `<script>` тег:

```
<script src='three.js'></script>
<script src='index.js'></script>
```

`three.js` - библиотека, котрую я хочу использовать с typescript'ом. Я не понимаю, как я должен настроить файл `tsconfig.json`, чтобы:

```
$ tsc --project tsconfig.json && node main.js
```

Скомпилировало рабочий результат. Так же вопрос - как мне импортировать `three.js` "тайпинги" в файл `index.ts`?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Typescript-setup

Comment: P A R C E L js  !